# "Сердитый" — причастие или прилагательное?

Tags: морфология, прилагательные, причастия

"Сердитый" причастие или прилагательное?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот есть как раз на эту тему рассуждение http://www.e-reading.mobi/chapter.php/1006422/171/Shanskiy_-_Lingvisticheskie_detektivy.html , так что прилагательное

Answer (score 2):

Ознакомился с приведенной в ответе ММ ссылкой, несколько сумбурной по стилю изложения, но содержащей зерно истины. Как я для себя переформулировал прочитанный материал. Слово сердитый по смыслу связан со словами сердце и сердить, является прилагательным и образовано при помощи суффикса -ит от основы 'серд'. Замечу в скобках,  что **'серд' не имеет значения "гнев, злоба"**, как о том сообщает автор сетевой заметки. 'Серд' - то, что внутри человека определяет его характер и личность, то есть саму суть сапиенса. Далее чисто мои рассуждения. Суффикс -ит в прилагательных "передает" ослабленный признак чего-то. Боевой - боев-ит-ый, деловой - делов-ит-ый, мозговой - мозгов-ит-ый, родовой - родов-ит-ый, масть - маститый и тд. Сердитым может быть и добрый человек, временно чем-то расстроенный. Какие же прилагательные выражают наш сабж в полной мере, as is, как говорится?

Добросердечный, **серд**обольный - со знаком плюс, жестоко**серд**ый - со знаком минус. Получается, что сердитый человек - это не всерьез и надолго, а пока не успокоится и не простит своего  обидчика или какого несмышленого шалопая. "Я больше на тебя не сержусь" - формула прощения и примирения.

Причастия к глаголу сердить : сердящий, сердивший, сердимый, серженный.

Comment: значит если кто то проголодается и скажет " я голодный" то он голоден надолго. Мне кажется ,что сердитый может быть и причастием и прилагательным ,все зависит от места использования, а не от суффиксов...